# MergeContent NiFi, parquet/json input

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use the NiFi MergeContent to merge multiple parquet files together.
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html
The parquet files I have obtained via the ConvertRecord operator.

Please let me know if you have an example on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Records, as you have used ConvertRecord, consider using [MergeRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeRecord/index.html) instead of MergeContent.